# Cross compile Qt6 with yocto sdk - QWayland is missing requirements

Tags: linux, qt, cross-compiling, arm64

I want to cross compile Qt6.5 with a yocto SDK.
First I compile a Qt host build without problems.

```
qt-host -> installation folder of host-build
qt-hostbuild -> build folder of host build
qt6-build -> build folder of device
qt6-device -> installation folder of device-build
```

Host-Build:

```
cmake ../qt5/ -GNinja -DFEATURE_developer_build=ON -DQT_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DQT_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/qt-host
```

Cross-Compile:

```
../qt5/configure -release -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebkit -sysroot $HOME/sdk/sysroot/cortexa53-crypto-linux -qt-host-path $HOME/qt-host -extprefix $HOME/qt6-device -prefix /home/qt6 -- -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/toolchain.cmake
```

But when I want to configure the build for the device I get a hint during the configuration of the qtwayland submodule.

CMake Warning at qtwayland/src/CMakeLists.txt:25 (message):
QtWayland is missing required dependencies, nothing will be built.
Although this could be considered an error, the configuration will still
pass as coin (Qt's continuous integration system) will fail the build if
configure fails, but will still try to configure the module on targets that
are missing dependencies.

My device use Wayland with Weston compositor. The wayland-scanner binary is in the sysroot/x86_64-linux/usr/bin folder available.

I added three more outputs to the CMakeLists.txt of qtwayland were I output the variables Wayland_FOUND, Wayland_VERSION and WaylandScanner_FOUND.

```
[QtWayland] Wayland_FOUND="TRUE"
[QtWayland] Wayland_VERSION="1.20.0"
[QtWayland] WaylandScanner_FOUND="FALSE"
```

So the main issue is that WaylandScanner_FOUND is false I suppose.
But why is it not found?
Here is my toolchain.cmake file. Is something missing?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
include_guard(GLOBAL)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(TARGET_SYSROOT /home/sdk/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-linux)
set(CROSS_COMPILER /home/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-linux)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${TARGET_SYSROOT})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${TARGET_SYSROOT})

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig)
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILER}/aarch64-linux-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILER}/aarch64-linux-g++)

set(QT_COMPILER_FLAGS "-march=armv8-a+crc+crypto ")
set(QT_COMPILER_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2 -pipe")
set(QT_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

include(CMakeInitializeConfigs)

function(cmake_initialize_per_config_variable _PREFIX _DOCSTRING)
  if (_PREFIX MATCHES "CMAKE_(C|CXX|ASM)_FLAGS")
    set(CMAKE_${CMAKE_MATCH_1}_FLAGS_INIT "${QT_COMPILER_FLAGS}")

    foreach (config DEBUG RELEASE MINSIZEREL RELWITHDEBINFO)
      if (DEFINED QT_COMPILER_FLAGS_${config})
        set(CMAKE_${CMAKE_MATCH_1}_FLAGS_${config}_INIT "${QT_COMPILER_FLAGS_${config}}")
      endif()
    endforeach()
  endif()

  if (_PREFIX MATCHES "CMAKE_(SHARED|MODULE|EXE)_LINKER_FLAGS")
    foreach (config SHARED MODULE EXE)
      set(CMAKE_${config}_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "${QT_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endforeach()
  endif()

  _cmake_initialize_per_config_variable(${ARGV})
endfunction()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it.
I found the final hint at [Qt6 cross compile for imx6 with Wayland support](https://forum.qt.io/topic/139492/qt6-cross-compile-for-imx6-with-wayland-support/5)

You have to compile the Wayland-support also for the host-build!